# Flutter test - Force rebuild of a widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-build

I'm trying to write tests to my flutter widgets.

Let's say I have this stateful widget:

```dart
class A extends StatefulWidget {
  const A();
  
  @override
  AState createState() => AState();
}

class AState extends State<A> {
  bool value = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final newValue = getNewValue(); // When the widget is rebuilt, I'm getting a value which can be `false` or `true`. I just want the widget to perfom actions if it changed;
    if (value != newValue) {
      setState(() {
        value = newValue;
      });
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        if (mounted) {
          // Do something, like show a snackbar for example
        }
      });
    }
    return const SizedBox.shrink();
  }
}
```

When the widget rebuilds, it looks if the value from `getNewValue` changed and rebuilds itself and then performs some actions with `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`. (I only want the widget to perform this action when it rebuilds, and not subscribing to `getNewValue` is wanted in my case).

Anyway, I wrote a test for this and where I pump the widget

```dart
// Mock `getNewValue` here so it returns `true`
const widget = A();
await tester.pumpWidget(widget);
await tester.pump();
// Verify the action after the `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` as been done
```

which works fine.

But now I want to force the widget to rebuild to test its behavior.

This is how I managed to do it (I call `setState`):

```dart
// Mock `getNewValue` here so it returns `false` (change since last build)
tester.state<AState>(find.byType(A)).setState(() {});
await tester.pump();
await tester.pump();
// Verify the action after the `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` as been done
```

And this works fine too.

---

However, calling the `setState` raises the warning

```
The member 'setState' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'.dart(invalid_use_of_protected_member)
```

and this trick won't work for a `StatelessWidget`

---

I was wondering what was the proper way to force a rebuild of a widget in a flutter test?